# Jquery Var Returned As object

Tags: jquery, object, var

I'm trying to pass a variable from one function to another, but the var elmId is being returned as an object and giving an error. When we click on any of the generated divs we should be able to change the size of the div by choosing a width / height value from the drop down menus.

I'm trying to pass the clicked div id which is elmId to function displayVals but it is not working. If we replace "#"+elmId in the function displayVals with the actual id of the first div created with is "#divid1" then it works. Why is the value of var elmId not being passed to displayVals

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <style>
    .aaa{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ccc;}
    button{width:100px; height:20px;}    
    </style>

<button class="idiv">div</button>
<select id="width">
    <option>100px</option>
    <option>200px</option>
    <option>300px</option>
</select>
<select id="height">
    <option>100px</option>
    <option>200px</option>
    <option>300px</option>
</select>
<p></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var divId = 1;

$("button").click(function(){
        var elm = $('<div id=divid' + divId + ' class=aaa></div>');
        elm.appendTo('p');
        divId++;
});

$("p").click(function(e){
    var elmType = $(e.target)[0].nodeName,
    elmId = $(e.target)[0].id;
    return displayVals(elmId);
    });
function displayVals(elmId) {
    var iwidth = $("#width").val();
    var iheight = $("#height").val();
    $("#"+elmId).css({width:iwidth, height:iheight});
    console.log(elmId);
    }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, there's no need to do `$(e.target)[0].id;`. When you do this, you're putting the element into a jQuery object, then pulling it right back out. Just do `e.target.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.divs{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ccc;}
button{width:100px; height:20px;}    
.selected{background:#dd0000;}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divId=1,selecteddiv="";
$("button").click(function(){
    $('p').append('<div id="divid'+divId+'" class="divs"></div>');
    divId++;
});

$(".divs").live("click",function(){
    selecteddiv=$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});

function displayVals() {
    if(selecteddiv!=""){
        var iwidth = $("#width").val();
        var iheight = $("#height").val();
        $("#"+selecteddiv).css({width:iwidth, height:iheight});
    }
}

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
</script>
```

- button will create the `divid[X]`
- as you're generating them dynamically you need to you `live` (as they don't exist when `click` event is being attached to class `.divs`)
- click on one of the `.divs` will put the ID name inside `selecteddiv`
- just to show you which one is selected the `.selected` class will be added to this div
- when you'll change the value `.change` event will kick in and if selecteddiv isn't empty then it will change the width and height
- you can drop the last line `displayVals();` as you don't have any divs created at the begining

I hope that's helpful enough :)

Cheers

G.

Comment: Great, that works. I see what you did. Can you explain the purpose of return false.

Comment: sorry old habit, you can remove it, it's preventing the default call to action when you're adding a click even to anchor (not relevant in this case) :)

Comment: What is the difference between 
var selecteddiv = and 
seleceddiv without the var infront

Comment: If you'll use var name outside of the function you'll be able to set a value to it from inside, you can get and set the value as long as you won't use var name again e.g. Inside a function, sorry a bit confusing but I'm writing from my iPhone right now :) I've used one line here to set both the global variables but it's the same as I'm separating them with coma, you can use var divid=1; var selecteddiv=""; cheers